# Dataframe transformation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and Scala. I have a dataframe that has huge amounts of data. The schema is like this one.

Lets call this `dataframe empDF`:

```
       id   name      emp_id  code  date
       1    Andrew    D01     C101  2012-06-14
       2    James     D02     C101  2013-02-26
       3    James     D02     C102  2013-12-29
       4    James     D02     C101  2010-09-27
       5    Andrew    D01     C101  2013-10-12
       6    Andrew    D01     C102  2011-10-13
```

I read this data from the database as a `DataFrame[Row]` object. Now I have to perform the following steps:

For each row with code C101 level greater than 1 must be set and for other codes level should be 0.If there is no previous record,
the level is set to `1`. If there is a previous record that is two or more years older than that record, level is set to `2`.
After this step dataframe should look like this

```
       id   name      emp_id  code  date         level
       1    Andrew    D01     C101  2012-06-14     2
       2    James     D02     C101  2013-02-26     2
       3    James     D02     C102  2012-12-29     0
       4    James     D02     C101  2010-09-27     1
       5    Andrew    D01     C101  2009-10-12     1
       6    Andrew    D01     C102  2010-10-13     0
```

The first and second row has level `2` because there is an older record of this employee and the date difference between the two rows is more than two years. The row with level `1` is because there is no record with a previous date and the row with level '0' is because we have marked all codes to 0 level other then C101

Now for rows with level 2 we have to check that if code C102 is apply on those employee within last year if apply then set level to 3 otherwise do not change the level. And in the final result dataframe all rows other than code C101 should be dropped.

After above two steps the resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
     id name    emp_id  code  date       level
     1  Andrew  D01     C101  2012-06-14   2
     2  James   D02     C101  2013-02-26   3
     4  James   D02     C101  2010-09-27   1
     5  Andrew  2013    C101  2013-10-12   1
```

Notice that the first row has level `2` because this employee has no C102 within last year however second row have C102 within last year.
How can I do that in Scala using the dataframe api, and functions like `map`, `flatmap`, `reduce`, etc.?

Comment: What have you tried? What result did you get, versus what you expected? See [sscce](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: Also, I tried to clean up the English, but you should double check that my interpretation was accurate. In the future, remember to use *short* sentences and be clear about what you reference. (Use 'record' rather than 'it'. Your use of 'history' is also very strange.) And, by the way, if you're showing no 'tried' code it is unlikely you'll get help - and your question might be closed.

Comment: "Gaudiness"? Why, yes! I *am* the most gaudy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [window functions](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val window = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("date")
val lagCol = lag(col("date"), 1).over(window)
val diff = datediff(col("date"), col("previousDate"))
val level = when(
  col("previousDate").isNull || (diff <= 730), 1
).otherwise(2)

val newDF = empDF
  .where(col("code") === "C101")
  .withColumn("previousDate", lagCol)
  .withColumn("level", level)
  .drop("previousDate")

newDF.orderBy("id").show

+---+------+------+----+----------+-----+
| id|  name|emp_id|code|      date|level|
+---+------+------+----+----------+-----+
|  1|Andrew|   D01|C101|2012-06-14|    1|
|  2|James |   D02|C101|2013-02-26|    2|
|  4|James |   D02|C101|2010-09-27|    1|
+---+------+------+----+----------+-----+
```

Comment: @thanx Daniel de Paula.  I really appreciate your answer. I have one more step that on resulting dataframe which is newDF in your answer i need to check if there is code C102 on the employee with in last year if that then mark this row as level 3.

Comment: @AtifShahzad, but in the first step you remove all lines with code different from C101, so there won't exist any row with code C102. I don't really understand.

Comment: in first step we need only C101 to process but when we processed it then in  last step we need to check if there is any C102 on only processed rows in first step. First dataframe may also have C103, C104 and others but we need to check only C102 in last step.

Comment: @AtifShahzad I'm sorry, I still don't understand. Could you edit your question with your explanation and an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Input data
val df = {
    import org.apache.spark.sql._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    import java.time.LocalDate

    val simpleSchema = StructType(
        StructField("id", IntegerType) ::
        StructField("name", StringType) ::
        StructField("emp_id", StringType) ::
        StructField("code", StringType) ::
        StructField("date", DateType) :: Nil)

    val data = List(
        Row(1, "Andrew", "D01", "C101", java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2012, 6, 14))),
        Row(2, "James", "D02", "C101", java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2013, 2, 26))),
        Row(3, "James", "D02", "C102", java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2013, 12, 29))),
        Row(4, "James", "D02", "C101", java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2010, 9, 27)))
    )    

    spark.createDataFrame(data.asJava, simpleSchema)
}
df.show()
// Filter and level calculation.
val df2 = df.filter(col("code") === "C101").
    withColumn("level", when(datediff(col("date"), min(col("date")).over(Window.partitionBy("emp_id"))) >= 365 * 2, 2).otherwise(1))
df2.show()
```